# jquery autocomplete unresponsive script

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress plugin where I'm trying to populate an autocomplete textbox using jquery and the source is from the database.

jquery script

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/plugin-name/php-file.php'?>"
    });
```

html

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
```

php

```
global $wpdb;
$code = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT suburb as label, post_code as code
        FROM Sheet1
        ",ARRAY_A
        );  
echo(json_encode($code));
```

but when I run this, the script crashes.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Please provide more details. What is the error you are receiving? Is the PHP crashing or the JS? Have you verified that the source URL as it is output by PHP actually exists?

Comment: using firebug console, in the response tab it returns the list of from the database but there was an error: Firebug response size limit has been reached.

Comment: firebug console response: [{"label":"Suburb","code":"Postcode"}.....

Comment: Sounds like too much is being returned? Maybe you should add a limit to the query?

Comment: how many rows are returned? autocomplete shouldnt have more then say -  25 results in it, otherwise it will become unusable.

Comment: @mkoryak as you can see in my question, the query selects all rows from the database. and it returns for about 15k of rows.

Comment: The example at jquery UI autocomplete page says ´value´ instead of ´code´ as the second json key.I don't know but it might be the problem.

Comment: @tpaksu actually it worked that way, I just set the query limit into 25 and it works. thanks to mkoryak for giving that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't set the query filter:

```
global $wpdb;
$code = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT suburb as label, post_code as code
    FROM Sheet1
    WHERE suburb like '%" . $_GET["term"] . "%'
    LIMIT 0,25
    ",ARRAY_A
    );  
echo(json_encode($code));
```

But of course you need to sanitize the `$_GET["term"]` part.

Comment: right. I've already fixed my code and it fairly looks like this. thanks man. :)